# How I can drag and drop with AutoKey script? or altenatives? (My right click is broken)

Tags: scripts, autokey

Please I need a code script for AutoKey or alternative. I speak Spanish.
I need this because my right click is broken and I'm poor.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible to substitute right-click dragging with a script. However, it is possible to assign a single right-click event to a keystroke, so that at least, right-click menus are again accessible. In many cases, however, one can already summon right-click menu's with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

There are multiple possibilities to emulate a mouse click. One is provided by `xdotool`, which is not by default installed. Once installed, assign the following command to a hotkey in order to emulate a right mouse click.

```
xdotool keyup Control click 3
```

Adapt the part `keyup Control` to the hotkey you choose. This `xdotool` command simulates releasing the modifier key. Suppose you use a combination with <kbd>Control</kbd> for your hotkey. Without `keyup`, the key may still will be pressed while right clicking, and some applications may interpret holding the <kbd>Control</kbd> key while right-clicking differently. Therefore, we first simulate releasing the <kbd>Control</kbd> key before sending the right click. Use `Alt`, `Shift`, `Super` for the other keys. If you have a hotkey with two modifier keys, issue two keyup statements as in `keyup Control keyup Alt`.